# How to set same display format in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, format, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, display

We use an MS Access database for a couple of processes, but two of my co-workers see the numbers in different formats in the same database and that’s a problem sometimes.

For example:
33.743,000
33,743.000

Where can I set both to have the same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused by different *regional settings* of for number formats in Windows.

Adjust these to match - or leave them as is.

The difference shouldn't cause problems for display - that's the purpose of these settings.

However, if you use the format for export of data, some method must be used to force a format of the exported data.